# How do I make shell script repeat every 5 minutes

Tags: bash, loops, shell

How do I make this shell script repeat every five minutes?

I use it in service.d

```
#!/system/bin/sh

sleep 60 

su -c CLASSPATH=/storage/emulated/0/DisplayToggle.dex app_process / DisplayToggle 0
```

I have a phone with a broken screen, and I want to use it as an android TV, and I want to make the screen always off,

Answer (score 2):

You can use a while loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    code-X_Y
    sleep $((60*4)) # we already wait 1mn, so need 4 more
done
```

Or use your script *as-is*, and schedule it in **crontab** or with a **systemd timer**.

Comment: Post a new question for this. Nothing related to your original post